# Convert DFA to Regular Expression

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions, simulation

In this old exam-task I don't understand all the steps to convert the DFA below to a Regular Expression. The $q_2$ state is eliminated first.
The provided solution to eliminate $q_2$ is:

If we first eliminate $q_2$ we obtain an intermediate automata with $3$ states 
$(q_0$,$q_1,q_3)$ such that:

> 1. We go from $q_0$ to $q_1$ with RE $a+ba$
> 2. We go from $q_0$ to $q_3$ with RE $bb$
> 3. We go from $q_1$ to $q_1$ with RE $ba$
> 4. We go from $q_1$ to $q_3$ with RE $a+bb$

I don't understand nr2. $q_3$ can also be reached using RE $aa$. Why is this left out?

[image]

:

[image]

:

[image]

Comment: The book *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* by Hopcroft, Ullman, Motwani describes this method of conversion of a DFA to a regular expression in detail. It is a very convenient method but requires some practice.

Comment: Also, as an aside. The last image looks wrong and the final regular expression should be: bb + (a+ba)(ba)*(a+bb) since in the second image, q1 is looping on (ba)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conversion in each step forms REs that describe

- The previous direct edge from one state to another and
- the path(s) that use(s) only the removed state as an intermediate state.

In your example, the path for $aa$ goes through $q_1$, which is not removed in this step. Thus it is not added to the RE.

Answer (score 2):

The RE "aa" is not left out. First "a" in transaction between $q_0$ and $q_1$, second "a" between q1 and q3. Since this pair of transitions doesn't involve $q_2$ we don't consider it in the first stage of the algorithm, where we're eliminating $q_2$.

Answer (score -2):

it is not left out , see q3 cn still be reachable using "aa" from intial state q1 , just **tk 2nd term from unioned terms** and then pick **'a'** from **(a+ba)** , tk **(ba)*** as **NULL String** and then take **2nd 'a'** from **(a+bb)** : so by concatenation we got "aa" and we reached final state q3

Comment: What does this add over older answers? Also, I find your post hard to follow.

Comment: first of all u ve made a mistake in a question. you ve changed the order of a loop at state q1 , it is supposed to be (ba)* and not (ab)* , then i pointed out a simpler way to show you tht "aa" isnt left out , directly from the regular expression you got at the last